# Why android GPS is not able to find location untill google map is on even if my phone supports A-GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I have make an android application which help us to get GPS Location using A-gps in my android phone. I am getting latitude and longitude successfully in Metro Cities of my country, but when I am going to some forest area,GPS do not get location and for this I need to run GPRS of my phone,after running google map once in my phone ,GPS successfully gets latitude and longitude even if I closes my internet connection or remove sim card from my phone. But since I do not want to use google map, what should I do now and why it is happening?? Any help will be appreciable

Comment: I've experienced the same phenomenon on a samsung galaxy s2, android 4.1. The GPS does not work at all if there is no internet connection and GPS was not used recently with internet connection. I think this is a bug of the AGPS implementation. AGPS requires up to date correction data, which is acquired through the internet. Pure GPS does not need this data. However, if internet is not available, the GPS system of the phone should revert to pure GPS instead of AGPS. It lacks to do so and waits until it knows the correction data.

Comment: This problem is not connected to google maps, but to the GPS system. Once the GPS system loaded the correction data over the internet, you can switch the internet connection off and AGPS will work until the GPS system decides that the correction data is too old (some hours for my case).

Comment: @Daniel S This is then an unusable Smartphone. GPS has to work with no Internet within 45s when having good view to sky, otherwise return the phone and by a better one. To make sure it is not your programmimg fault donwload a well running GPS app like Motion-X GPS. And look if they get a GPS signal.

Comment: How long between you location updates?

Comment: @AlexWien: I fully agree with you that the GPS system is then implemented in an undesired way. I do oppose that it is an "unusable Smartphone". It works perfectly in 99% of the use cases. I've checked this problem with at least 4 apps from the store, not made by me, including google maps. It is the same phenomenon with all apps tested. This is also known by Wikipedia: "Some A-GPS devices do not have the option of falling back to standalone or autonomous GPS." ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS#Description )

Comment: Such a smartphone then has very limited GPS functionality. Which makes it unsuable for GPS applications which should work outdoors.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a long time (several minutes) to get the GPS location with high precision. However, if you enable network based location (e.g. cell tower, WiFi), it's way faster but with lower precision.

As a result, you should listen to all the providers with `LocationManager`, and figure out which provides the best location. Or, if your app targets Android 8 and above, you can use the [Location APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) provided with Google Play Services, which hides the details as using `LocationManager` directly.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that it is not the fault of your phone or its operation system version.
Download a well working known GPS App, look if they get a GPS signal without internet.
Place it under very good cointions: free view to sky, outside dense city, at least an open place.

You should get a signal within one minute, maybe if the phone has a poor built-in GPS antenna, a bit more, wait some minutes.

If the well working foreign app still don't get GPS it's an Operating system bug.
If you get one, then it´s your fault, and it is worth for further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

****first check your GPS working or not properly with ***ANDROITS GPS TEST***. 
if it finds and fixes satellite do not worry. as AGPS is fast , standlone GPS needs to have much more time to fix on its own especially in city as many radio waves disturbs GPS fixure.
better first fix with AGPS and then you can turn off data or internet, still it will work as it already had its location and satellites fixed.
with standlone GPS it takes huge time and battery.****

Answer (score 0):

If your phone use GPS h/w to get the location information, it don't require any internet connection. It should be able to get the location fix using GPS without the help of internet. But it may take some time to get the location fix.
You can install the this free app from play-store to test the GPS of your phone : "TestYourGPS".

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eorsavik.testyourgps